# Stuck in a infinite loop after inputing the exit condition.

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to make this run in a loop until a non-numeric input is given.  The problem is that when I input a letter to exit the while loop, it goes into an infinite loop.  It also goes into the first if statement and continues to loop through that.  If someone has any ideas on how to fix this, it would be great.

```
int counter;
int input[100]
int num = 1
while (input[num] == 0)
{
    printf("score #%d:", counter);
    scanf("%d",&input[num]);

    if (input[num] <= 0){
        printf("you cannot use negative numbers\n");
        continue;
    }
    if (input[num] >= 100){
        printf("you cannot use numbers greater than 100\n");
        continue;
    }
    num++;
    counter++;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all,`num` is supposed to be 0 as array index starts from 0 not 1.

Then,you have `input[num]==0` in the condition in the `while` . You test using an uninitialized variable as `input` has not been initialized. This is the same for `counter`.

Your code won't compile as you have missed the `;` at the end of line 2 and 3.

Lastly,replace your `scanf` with the following code:

```
if(scanf("%d",&input[num])==0)
{printf("non-numeric character entered .Exiting loop...\n");
scanf("%*s");// asterick tells scanf to discard scanned string(clear the entered char)
break;
}
```

So finally,the modified code:

```
int counter=1; // initialize variable
int input[100]; //semicolon here
int num = 0; //num must be 0
while (1) //infinite loop
{
    printf("score #%d:", counter);

    if(scanf("%d",&input[num])==0) //if no value is scanned
{printf("non-numeric character entered .Exiting loop...\n");
scanf("%*s");// asterick tells scanf to discard scanned string(clear the entered char)
break;
}

    if (input[num] <= 0 )
        printf("you cannot use negative numbers\n");

    else if (input[num] >= 100)
        printf("you cannot use numbers greater than 100\n");
   else{
    num++;
    counter++;}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that when `scanf` is provided with a non-numeric input when you try reading with `%d` format, the non-numeric data does not get removed from the buffer. When your loop reaches `scanf` again, it gets the same data, and continues failing in an infinite loop.

To fix this, remove non-numeric input when `scanf` does not read a proper number of items:

```
int readCount = scanf("%d",&input[num]);
if (readCount != 1) {
    scanf("%*s");
    printf("Please enter a valid number.\n");
    continue;
}
```

Note that your loop's ending condition is incorrect, because `num` is always past the last element that has been read. You can fix it like this:

```
while (num < 100)
{
    ... // Read and error checks go here
    if (input[num] == 0) {
        break;
    }
    num++;
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: +1 for nice use of `"%*s"`.  Might want to mention about `EOF`.

Comment: Will this make it that when I enter a letter it will break out of the loop?  i thought that when the input is a number ,'input[num]==0' is true.  So will this not break the loop for any entered number?

Comment: @Chris The problem is that when you check `input[num]==0` in the header of the `while` loop, `num` is already "plus one" from the location where the last input is stored. If users enter a non-numeric value, the loop will continue, because of the use of `continue` operator right after `scanf("%*s")`.